# What user permissions required in SQL Server to run DBCC Reseed command on a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am a newbie. Can someone please let me know what permissions do a sql_login user requires to run a DBCC RESEED and how to check if the user has the permission to execute it.

Comment: SQL Server documentation is remarkably good for questions like this since there's always a Permissions section. So maybe [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176057.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

**Permissions**
Caller must own the table, or be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

Comment: Taken straight from the freely available MSDN documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms176057.aspx